# INDEX look up for Max exact match value in more than one column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for the biggest value on a table that will return a value on another column. INDEX, MAX, and MATCH work perfectly for this but only if I have a single column of values for MATCH. My issue is that we divide the values I'm looking for in 2 different columns and I only need the biggest value within the two. I can't return a value with MATCH because it only searches for a value in a single column. Is there a way to do a MATCH search for a value in 2 columns at the same time?

[image: TABLE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try abandoning INDEX() and MATCH(), try a different approach.

Create a new array based on the data in the entire range using the usual comparison of the cell value with the result of the MAX() function - if the cell contains this value, then write down its row number, otherwise leave the value blank.

```
...IF(B2:C7=MAX(B2:C7);ROW(B2:C7);"")...
```

Now the MIN() function will return you the first, smallest line number where this value was encountered.

```
...MIN(IF(B2:C7=MAX(B2:C7);ROW(B2:C7);""))...
```

Add the column letter in front and you have the address of the desired cell. INDIRECT() at this address will return the desired (first possible) value. Since this is an array formula, don't forget to end the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

```
{=INDIRECT("A"&MIN(IF(B2:C7=MAX(B2:C7);ROW(B2:C7);"")))}
```

[image: StepByStep]

Comment: I was able to replicate this, thank you.

Comment: On a side note, can I do this if the data under the A column is in a separate sheet or another range that isn't adjacent to the data?

Comment: @LightningBolt Yes, you certainly can. The formula doesn't get too complicated. Is the range of values to search solid? Or is it also divided into separate columns on separate sheets? By the way, does your version of Excel support the MAXIFS() function? This would make things a lot easier (I didn't mention this solution because so many people still use older versions of Excel where these features didn't exist yet)

Comment: The Max values that I look for are in different columns that aren't adjacent to each other or adjacent to the column with the downtime descriptions. I use Office 2013.

Comment: @LightningBolt Unfortunately, we will not be able to discuss all the details of such data construction in the comments. All ranges start from same row? All ranges have same size? I propose to ask one more question, in the text of which you will describe in detail the existing data structure. Please do not use the screenshot - copy the range of cells from the Excel sheet and paste it into the question text, such data is easier to reproduce for the test dataset.

Comment: First set of data is in A17:G50
Second set is in I17:P31

I'd need to look through both sets and pull the greatest value and the Downtime#/desc from the column of said value.

the columns on both sets are
No, Code, Downtime Desc, J1, J2, and Total.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: No, with such an organization of data, it is impossible to get the job done correctly with formulas alone. (Actually, it is possible, but very cumbersome). It is better to use the Get&Transform tools from the Data tab: merge all tables into one, select all rows with the maximum idle value (there may be more than one), and display the entire list in a separate table. In this case, important data will not be missed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the LARGE function. For example, the formula below returns the largest value.

```
=LARGE(B2:C5,1)
```

[image]